# Get nearest all Y values on click of anywhere of linechart using highchart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a line chart with multiple trend lines. I want to display the nearest Y values for all trend lines on click of anywhere in chart.

[image: Screen shot]

In the screenshot, I want to display all Y values (i.e., displayed in Tooltip) on right side panel corresponding to bitrates on clicking anywhere in chart.

Can I get tooltip data on charts click event?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @Sajeetharan What you want to see? I can help if you can let me know what you r looking for. It's a piece of long code. If you want me, I ll create a JSFiddle.

Comment: yes create jsfiddle

Comment: Ok..Give me some time.. Thanks in Adv!!!

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hi can u help me with this. I am not able to create fiddle because of proxy issues.

Comment: ok wait i will checkk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126891/discussion-between-p-jagajit-prusty-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: Is a legend on the right side? If so, you can use plugin from here: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/10/Value-In-Legend

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a workaround to find all y values for all trend line. But it's expensive as we have to do single iteration over x axis values for a single trend line.

```
chart:{
  events: {
    click: function(e){
       console.log(getAllYValues(this, e.xAxis[0].value)) //e.xAxis[0].value is the x- coordinate where it got clicked
    }
  }
}

   function getAllYValues(chartObj, xValue) {
        var _series0 = chartObj.series[0].points;
        var key = getXValue(_series0, xValue); //Get Nearest X value
        var yValues = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < chartObj.series.length; i++) {
          yValues[i].bitsPerSecond = chartObj.series[i].points[key].y
        }
        return yValues;
    }
function getXValue(points, xValue) {
      for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
          if (points[i].x >= xValue) {
            if(i > 0) {
              return Math.abs(points[i].x - xValue) < Math.abs(points[i-1].x - xValue) ? i : i-1; //Get nearest X value

            }
            else{return i;}
          }
      }
    }
```